# Enabling TLS 1.2 with latest version of OkHttpClient

Tags: android, tls1.2, okhttp

We have an Android application that uses  OkHttpClient to call our REST services.  We need to enable TLS 1.2 for those calls.

Has anybody done this with the latest version of the OKHttpClient?  I cannot find any clear sample code that just does that.  I would have expected that it would be  a simple couple of lines of code but apparently not.  Our code is built for SDK version 24.

Thanks so much for your help.